# Is it possible to dedicate a portion of shared memory to each thread?

Tags: multithreading, cuda, gpgpu

I am using CUDA 10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to know whether it is possible to dedicate a portion of shared memory to each thread. What I mean by that is, let's say, I want to have a relatively large array private to each thread that won't fit into registers and putting the array into shared memory will introduce race conditions since each thread on a block would have access to it. Therefore it is very interesting to me to use a portion of shared memory as "register" so that I will avoid race conditions. I understand that it will limit my occupancy by limiting the number of threads I could use in an SM but the trade-off is worth it in my case. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to *dedicate* a shared memory allocation (static or dynamic) to a particular thread. Shared memory only has block scope.

It is, however, perfectly possible to devise an indexing scheme whereby threads within a block exclusively use unique locations within a block scope shared memory allocation. For example:

```
template<int nthreads, int words_per_thread>
__global__
void kernel(..)
{
    __shared__ int buffer[nthreads * words_per_thread];

    int* localbuff = &buffer[threadIdx.x * words_per_thread];

    // localbuff is now safely indexed from [0] to [words_per_thread-1]

}
```

Another possible method would be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template<typename T>
class sr_
{
  T *sp;
  public:
  __device__
  sr_(T *_sd) { sp = _sd;}
  __device__
  T &operator[](int idx){return sp[blockDim.x*idx+threadIdx.x];}
};
// for statically allocated shared memory
#define SREG(size,type,block_size) \
  __shared__ type SREG_sdata[size*block_size]; \
  typedef type SREG_type; \
  sr_<SREG_type> sreg(SREG_sdata);
// for dynamically allocated shared memory
#define DSREG(type) \
  __shared__ type SREG_sdata[]; \
  typedef type SREG_type; \
  sr_<SREG_type> sreg(SREG_sdata);

const int BS = 8;

__global__ void k2(){
  SREG(8,float,BS)
  sreg[0] = 1.0f;
  printf("%f\n", sreg[0]);
}

int main(){

  k2<<<1,BS>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

It has the benefits that there is no possibility for one thread to index into another thread's space, and also that there cannot be any bank conflicts.  Note that this will not handle all use cases.  It would have to be modified, for example, if there were multiple kernels in the same module that used different data types for shared memory.